# Exit program in windows command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line

When in the command prompt: I am looking for a Windows equivalent of CTRL+C in unix and mac to force exit a program in a command prompt. Sometimes my program would just infinitaly wait for... something and I would like to close it without hitting CTRL+ALT+DELETE and force quitting the windows command prompt.
Thanks!

Comment: Ctrl+D also works sometimes.

Answer (score 20):

Ctrl + C will stop a program running from the command prompt, similar to other operating systems.

To force kill a process from the command prompt, use the following command:

> taskkill /F /IM process.exe

`/F` will force termination, `/IM` means you're going to provide the executable (image) name, and `process.exe` is the process to end.

Comment: Make sure to use "process name.exe" if it has a space!

Comment: How to get arround ERROR: The process "remoting_host.exe" with PID 8164 could not be terminated.
Reason: Access is denied.

Comment: Found it myself, going to Services and killing the service with the PID that was returned above.

Answer (score 15):

Actually, it's Ctrl+C on Windows too. Ctrl+Break usually works as well, but with some commands it has some interesting differing semantics compared to Ctrl+C (see `ping -t` for example).

Comment: Just wanted to add that Ctrl+Pause also works. Yes, Pause and Break are the same key for most computers, but in my case, and I am sure others, I have to press the FN key if I want to use the Break portion of that key. So, pressing Ctrl + FN + Break works, but so does Ctrl + Pause, which is great for those of us that want to use as few keys as possible.

Comment: According to my experience most program only stops by ctrl+break and less stop with ctrl+c

Answer (score 5):

Normally, that would be CTRL-BREAK (the PAUSE/BREAK key on a 101-key keyboard) but I think this can be disabled.

Give it a shot.

But this isn't really a programming question so I'm voting to shift it to [superuser](http://superuser.com).

Comment: Do you have any idea if there's an equiv. for a macbook keyboard?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Command to exit command prompt:

```
taskkill /IM cmd.exe
```